# SSL on embedded tomcat 8 (Spring boot) )is not working

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I generated symmetric key AES with 128 bit using the following command. 
`keytool -genseckey -alias myPvtKey -keyalg AES -keysize 128 -storetype jceks -keystore myPvt.jks`

gave the keystore password and keypassword as same.

```
server:
    port: 8080
    context-path: /myapp
 ssl:
  enabled: true
  protocol: SSL
  enabled-protocol: ssl3
  key-store: ${user.home}/myPvt.jks
  key-store-password: mypwd
  key-password: mypwd
  key-store-type: jceks
```

I try to access my application using firefox or chrome @ https://localhost:8080, I get.Chrome also throws Cipher mismatch. 
`An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8080. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)`

I ran sslscan on localhost:8080 it rejected all algorithms including AES. So not sure what to do next. Can any body please guide me on this.
Thanks,
AM

Comment: I voted to close this as off topic, since I thought it fell more under network/server configuration but I now see it as disputed, can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Were you able to get this working?